# How to setup Outlook to use Gmail mailbox and multiple "From" addresses

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I have a Gmail account and added multiple non-Gmail accounts to my Gmail.
On a Mac I could connect this Gmail to Mac Mail and setup Mail to allow different sent-to's (-> see great explanation: [Sending From Multiple "From" Addresses in MacOS Mail](https://www.lifewire.com/multiple-from-addresses-os-x-1172806)

Does anyone know how to do the same in Outlook?

PS: this allows me to view all my mail in one inbox on multiple devices (browser, phone, macbook (and hopefully laptop))

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think Outlook client has same feature as Mac Mail. You can try clicking “Other Email Address” in From drop-down menu to see if it helps.

[image]